# How to set state separately for each element when mapping through array in React

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-hooks, components, rendering

## I'm trying to create a component to add and remove guests and i created an array of the data each element should have so i can map through it and save some code lines but I'm having trouble to set individual state for every element i created.

## any thoughts?

## cheers.

For next time whats the best way to approach to set state when handling a mapped array?

is my way ok and just need to fix the way i set state to get the result I'm looking for or is my approach totally wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../styles/guests.css";

const Guests = ({ dataArr }) => {
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState({
    Adults: "0",
    Children: "0",
    Infants: "0",
    Pets: "0",
  });
  const [selectedChild, setSelectedChild] = useState(null);

  const handleChangeAmount = (ev, idx) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let newAmount = amount;
    if (ev.target.id === ev.target.closest("li").id) {
      if (ev.target.value === "1") {
        newAmount++;
        setAmount(newAmount);
      }
      if (ev.target.value === "0") {
        if (amount[idx] == "0") return;
        newAmount--;
        setAmount(newAmount);
      }
      console.log(amount[idx]);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };

  return (
    <ul className="container px-0">
      {dataArr?.map((item, idx) => {
        return (
          <li
            className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center pointer my-4"
            id={item.title}
            key={idx}
          >
            <div className="label-container d-flex flex-column ms-2">
              <label className="text-black d-flex align-items-start fw-semibold">
                {item.title}
              </label>
              <label className="subtitle text-secondary d-flex align-items-start fw-light">
                {item.subTitle}
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="amount-container d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center me-2">
              <button
                className="dropdown-item p-1 me-4"
                type="button"
                id={item.title}
                onClick={handleChangeAmount}
                value="0"
              >
                ➖
              </button>
              <span className="amount display-amount" id={item.title}>
                {amount.Adults.valueOf()}
              </span>
              <button
                className="dropdown-item p-1 ms-4"
                type="button"
                id={item.title}
                onClick={handleChangeAmount}
                value="1"
              >
                ➕
              </button>
            </div>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Guests;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have written full TypeScript solution for your problem including not only solution, but code quality recommendations too. In case, you have problems with TypeScript, I could represent solution via JavaScript.

You can find and try  solution on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-7clh2w?file=Guests.tsx

Comment: amazing solution thanks for the effort!